Python buildozer and numpy
Kivymd buildozer numpy
I’ve used Buildozer and Colab for 5 of my apps now for Google Play.
Compiling of APK and AAB has been successful till now.
I need to update one of them, a Navigation App. Here with the original error:
Error: in order to build Numpy you must set minimum NDK api (minapi) to 24, 
and also the Android NDK api (it should usually match android.minapi)

I’ve done that, and various combinations, and ran logcat, but I don't find the problem.
I am confident about other buildozer settings as I use them for other apps.
I have tried various websites to see if anyone else has the same problem, but not recently.
Note that the app compiled successfully about 6 months ago.
Can you help, or is this perhaps an issue for Github?
I think the problem is with buildozer, numpy and the NDK

Have you updated numpy since it last built successfully?

I have the same issue, and my app compiled successfully only 2 weeks ago, so I wonder if anything happenned in the last 2 weeks to cause this

I found this commit in the develop branch of python-for-android, there is a line in it that is exactly the error message we are getting, still investigating: the commit

thank you for response. Yes I have updated numpy (1.26)

Yes, the app compiled. Thanks

Changed these two APIs:

android.minapi = 24
android.ndk_api = 24

It’s working fine now.
